# Oracle PL/SQL Trigger (fire upon new rows inserted)

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE film (
  film_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  title varchar2(255),
  description varchar2(255),
  release_year NUMBER(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  language_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  original_language_id NUMBER(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  rental_duration NUMBER(3) DEFAULT 3 NOT NULL,
  rental_rate NUMBER(4,2) DEFAULT '4.99',
  length NUMBER(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  replacement_cost NUMBER(5,2) DEFAULT '19.99' NOT NULL,
  rating varchar2(8) DEFAULT 'G',
  special_features varchar2(255) DEFAULT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE language (
  language_id NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  name varchar2(20) NOT NULL
);
```

and the following constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE FILM ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LANGUAGEID FOREIGN KEY (LANGUAGE_ID) REFERENCES LANGUAGE (LANGUAGE_ID);

ALTER TABLE FILM ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ORLANGUAGEID FOREIGN KEY (ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE_ID) REFERENCES LANGUAGE (LANGUAGE_ID);
```

**The question is:**

Write an SQL trigger, e.g. named ​BI_FILM_LANG​, to append text to the description of every new film inserted into the database. It is based on the language (​language_id​) and the original language (​original_language_id​) of the film. The format of the text you append should be (replacing tokens):

```
Originally in ​<original language>
​ . Re-released in ​<language>
​ . Original language and language should be the name of the language from the             language table.
```

For example: If the following query was run:

```
INSERT INTO FILM (title, description, language_id, original_language_id ) VALUES  ('B Movie', 'Movie about wasps.', 1, 2);
```

It should produce the following when the following select statement is run (assuming B Movie’s id is 9999999):

```
SQL> SELECT description FROM FILM WHERE film_id = 9999999;

description 

---------------------------------------------------------
Movie about wasps. Originally in Italian. Re-released in English.
```

Comment: mysql <> Oracle  - which one are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I see that this looks like a homework question to write a Trigger. What's your attempt?

Answer (score -1):

1.You have to write a pragma autonomous block :

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE update_data (ol NUMBER,rl NUMBER,film_id NUMBER
                                )
IS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

  l_name  VARCHAR2(100);
  l_namerl    VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

 SELECT name   INTO l_name FROM language 
 WHERE language_id=ol;

  SELECT name INTO l_namerl FROM language 
 WHERE language_id=rl; 


  UPDATE film
  SET description=description||'.Originally in '||l_name||'. Re-released in '||l_namerl 

  WHERE film_id=film_id;

 COMMIT;    


END;
```

2.Trigger

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER sspr_air_tr
    AFTER INSERT
    ON film
    FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

 update_data(:new.language_id ,:new.original_language_id,:new.film_id);
END;
```

3.

```
INSERT INTO language VALUES (1,'English');
INSERT INTO language VALUES (2,'Italian');

INSERT INTO FILM (film_id,title, description, language_id, original_language_id ) VALUES  (100,'B Movie', 'Movie about wasps.', 1, 2);


SELECT * from film;
```

Comment: No need for a complicated workaround with a `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`.  simply **assign** the value in the row level trigger: `:new.description := .new.description||'.Originally in '||l_name||'. Re-released in '||l_namer` after retrieving the old and new language.

Comment: Thanks ! yes! You are right. I just added this would be one way to do this.

Comment: but why down voting my answer?

Comment: People are downvoting because your answer is wrong. It proposes using `pragma autonomous_transaction`, which is at best  unnecessary and indeed likely to cause problems.